# How to do slider 100% width and height?

Tags: html, css, slider

How to do slider 100% width and height?
It is not changed when you zoom in or out. It is like fixed.

Comment: what you tried? can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer updated

```
/* keyframes*/

@keyframes 
slideShow {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 transform:scale(1);
 -ms-transform:scale(1);
}
 5% {
 opacity: 1
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 30% {
 opacity: 0;
 transform:scale(1);
 -ms-transform:scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 transform:scale(1);
 -ms-transformm:scale(1);
}
}
 @-o-keyframes 
slideShow {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -o-transform:scale(1);
}
 5% {
 opacity: 1
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 30% {
 opacity: 0;
 -o-transform:scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 -o-transformm:scale(1);
}
}
 @-moz-keyframes 
slideShow {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transform:scale(1);
}
 5% {
 opacity: 1
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 30% {
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transform:scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 -moz-transformm:scale(1);
}
}
 @-webkit-keyframes 
slideShow {  0% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform:scale(1);
}
 5% {
 opacity: 1
}
 25% {
 opacity: 1;
}
 30% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transform:scale(1);
}
 100% {
 opacity: 0;
 -webkit-transformm:scale(1);
}
}
```

update this style with your existing style.

Comment: it doesn't work. width works great, but problem is with height

Comment: what is the issue in height?

Comment: I want my height(of first block-slider) to be like in http://mahno.com.ua/en/   when you zoom in or out, first block must fit the browser(100%). How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically should be enough to set height property to 100vh value it should do the trick. width property can stay at 100%

edit it is vh not vm